# Geting User Location and using coordinates as a string outside the didUpdateLocations

Tags: string, coordinates, cllocationmanager

I'm having a problem with user location and the rest of my code...

I've developed a code that retrieves restaurants from Foursquare API for a certain location. The problem I'm trying to solve is this:

This is the URL string that I use to retrieve the information (lat. and lon. are hardcoded just to get things started) :

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=51.51,-0.13&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735&radius=3000&oauth_token=A5ZDWL2DLXPZCQ3ZJESVOAKDMPQHSNNVWC3UMVOUOXPQHWRT&v=20121105
```

I've separated URL string in three parts, where the second part is current user location.

```
NSString *firstStringPart = @"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=";
    NSString *secondStringPart = currentLocationString;
    NSString *thirdStringPart = @"&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735&radius=3000&oauth_token=A5ZDWL2DLXPZCQ3ZJESVOAKDMPQHSNNVWC3UMVOUOXPQHWRT&v=20121105";
```

And then I want to append strings together

```
NSString *connectedUrlString = [[firstStringPart stringByAppendingString:secondStringPart] stringByAppendingString:thirdStringPart];
```

That all works if I put coordinates for second string part like this:

```
NSString *secondStringPart = @"51.51,-0.13";
```

I've also made a little test project to get user location and it's working with this code:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize locationManager, location;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self setLocationManager:[[CLLocationManager alloc] init]];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

    NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *lon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    location = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", lat, lon];

    NSLog(@"%@", location);
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}
```

Using NSLog I get the right output that I want to.

Finally, my question is, how do I get the user location in a variable and use it in the view DidLoad method as a `NSString *secondStringPart = currentLocationString;` right after [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]

Or am I doing something wrong?

I would appreciate your help, 
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED...

I've solved the problem...

I had to move my code to the `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations` method and do everything inside of it...